# How to find possible permutation of a list that contains images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to load an image using opencv and then splitting that image into 4 parts. I have saved all the images in a list and now i want to find out all the possible permutation combination.

This is my current code.

```
#Importing Libraries
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import glob
import itertools

#Importing Image
path = 'cat.jpg'
img = cv.imread(path)

#Seperating the height and width from the image data
(h, w) = img.shape[:2] 

#Finding the center
centerX, centerY = (w//2), (h//2) 

#spliting the image
topleft = img[0:centerY, 0:centerX]
topright = img[0:centerY, centerX:w]
bottomleft = img[centerY:h, 0:centerX]
bottomright = img[centerY:h, centerX:w]

#creating a new directory
os.mkdir('splits')

#Saving split images
cv.imwrite('./splits/1.jpg', topleft)
cv.imwrite('./splits/2.jpg', topright)
cv.imwrite('./splits/3.jpg', bottomleft)
cv.imwrite('./splits/4.jpg', bottomright)

#Putting the images in a list
img_data = []
files = glob.glob ('./splits/*.jpg')
for myfile in files:
    image = cv.imread(myfile)
    img_data.append(image)
```

I have tried to use the permutation function from the itertools library. But i don't think so it is working properly.

Comment: are you sure you're saving and reading from the correct folder?
from what i see, you're writing the split files in `cwd` while you're trying to read from a directory called `./splits`.

Comment: Yes actually i have manually moved the images from main directory to a new splits directory. This portion of the code is working perfectly fine. I want to know if there is any way to find out all the possible permutation combinations of the split images.
like [1,2,3,4] = [1,3,4,2], [3,2,4,1], [2,1,4,3] and so on. 4! is 24. So it will be 24 possible arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

I expaneded you code a little bit, ran this and it worked for me:

```
#Importing Libraries
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import os
from itertools import permutations

#Importing Image
path = 'cat.jpg'
img = cv.imread(path)

#Seperating the height and width from the image data
(h, w) = img.shape[:2] 

#Finding the center
centerX, centerY = (w//2), (h//2) 

#spliting the image
topleft = img[0:centerY, 0:centerX]
topright = img[0:centerY, centerX:w]
bottomleft = img[centerY:h, 0:centerX]
bottomright = img[centerY:h, centerX:w]


def concat_tile(im_list_2d):
    return cv.vconcat([cv.hconcat(im_list_h) for im_list_h in im_list_2d])
#creating a new directory
try:
    os.mkdir('splits')
    os.mkdir("./permutations")
except:
    pass

#Saving split images
cv.imwrite('./splits/1.jpg', topleft)
cv.imwrite('./splits/2.jpg', topright)
cv.imwrite('./splits/3.jpg', bottomleft)
cv.imwrite('./splits/4.jpg', bottomright)

#Putting the images in a list
img_data = []
files = glob.glob ('./splits/*.jpg')
print(files)
c = 0
for elem in permutations(files):
    perm_file = None
    im0 = cv.imread(elem[0])
    im1 = cv.imread(elem[1])
    im2 = cv.imread(elem[2])
    im3 = cv.imread(elem[3])
    im_tile = concat_tile([[im0, im1], [im2, im3]])
    cv.imwrite(f"permutations/perm_{c}.jpg", im_tile)
    c += 1
```

Ran into some trouble with creating the `permutations` folder locally, but you can work around that yourself and create it manually for now.
I have 24 files that are permutations like you described:

[image]

Also, here's how one of them looks:
[image]

Note the `vconcat` function and the user of `permutations`.

You can, of course, use a better description for you file names by splitting the path string, but that's easy.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Actually, what you have did above, this can be done more easily using "image_slicer" library. What i am trying to do i want to put all split images in a list and then want to find out all possible permutation and save it in a list again.